# Widget not updating activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-activity

I am implementing a widget with a collection.  I have the widget working fine, however, when a user clicks on an item in the collection, I want to open my app an pass and id, from the widget, to the `Main` `activity`, which, then, redirects the user to another `activity`.  The reason I do this is I need to refresh the `Main` activity first (I show the number of unread items).

What I have works the first time I click on an item in the widget collection.  However, if I press the home button and click on another item, my app just displays the last screen from the `Browser` activity (the second activity the user is directed to).  If I exit out of the app or click back, then go to the widget, it works as expected.  This issue only occurs when I "minimize" the app, while remaining on the 2nd `activity`.

I'm not sure if it has something to do with the `PendingIntent` in the widget service.

**Widget Service**

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {
    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        return new StackRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }
}

class StackRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory  {

    private List<Integer> mIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Context mContext;
    private int mAppWidgetId;

    public StackRemoteViewsFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
        mAppWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    public void onCreate() {
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mIds.size();
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);

        final Intent mi = new Intent(mContext, Main.class);

        final Bundle bun = new Bundle();
        bun.putInt("id", mIds.get(position));
        mi.putExtras(bun);

        final PendingIntent piMain = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, position, mi, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_text, piMain);
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text, mIds.get(position));

        return rv;
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        mIds = Utilities.GetIds(); //returns id's from a sqlite database
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

**Main.class**

```
public class Main extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){

        final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        final Intent browser = new Intent(this, Browser.class);

        final Bundle bun = new Bundle();
        bun.putInt("id", extras.getInt("id"));
        browser.putExtras(bun);

        startActivity(browser);
    }
}
```

**Browser.class**

```
public class BrowserPager extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private int mId = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle)
    {    
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.browser_pager);

        final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null)
        {
            mId = extras.getInt("id");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reread the section about widget collections:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent(int, android.app.PendingIntent) states:

> When setting the on-click action of items within collections (eg.
>   ListView, StackView etc.), this method will not work. Instead, use
>   {@link RemoteViews#setPendingIntentTemplate(int, PendingIntent) in
>   conjunction with RemoteViews#setOnClickFillInIntent(int, Intent).

To use a collection in a widget create an Intent to call your activity. That intent is added to a PendingIntent that is added to your collection view (list, stack, grid) using setPendingIntentTemplate. This all happens in the onUpdate method of your AppWidgetProvider class.
To add individual behavior to a single item you create another Intent containing extras about that single item and add it to the RemoteViews in getViewAt using setOnClickFillInIntent. The receiving Activity can read the extra parameters the usual way.

The whole PendingIntent code goes into the AppWidgetProvider e.g. like this:

```
final Intent mi = new Intent(mContext, Main.class)
    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
final PendingIntent piMain = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, position, mi, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.MyCollection, piMain);
```

Your getViewAt code would look more like this:

```
final Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
final Bundle bun = new Bundle();
bun.putInt("id", mIds.get(position));
fillInIntent.putExtras(bun);
rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_text, fillInIntent);
```

Comment: Ah, that worked. I did read that section, but must have overlooked that part.  Thanks!